# Cylindrical projection to sphere

Tags: matlab, geometry

I have a 2d array (lat*long) containing height information. I want to map this cylindrical projection to a actual sphere with radius r and plot it.

How would I do that? Sorry it so little info, but I'm completely lost right now ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Longitude and latitude are not cylindrical coordinates; rather, they are equivalent to azimuth and elevation in spherical coordinates.  At each latitude and longitude, you have a height (which may need to have the mean radius of the sphere added to it if it isn't the true height *from the center* already).

Check out the [sph2cart](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sph2cart.html) function, which converts from spherical to cartesian coordinates.  You'll have to convert from degrees to radians first.

Steps to take:

1. Create matrix (same size as original) with *just longitudes*.
2. Do the same for *just latitudes* (after this you  should have 3 matrices of the same size as your original - latitude, longitude, height).
3. Make sure those latitude and longitude matrices are in
   radians, not degrees
4. Make sure your height info is from *the
   center of the sphere*
5. Use `sph2cart` to get x,y,z matrices.
6. Use [surf](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/surf.html)(x,y,z) to plot the results

Notes on sph2cart from the documentation:

> [x,y,z] = sph2cart(azimuth,elevation,r) transforms the corresponding
>   elements of spherical coordinate arrays to Cartesian, or xyz,
>   coordinates. azimuth, elevation, and r must all be the same size (or
>   any of them can be scalar). azimuth and elevation are angular
>   displacements in radians from the positive x-axis and from the x-y
>   plane, respectively.